# confusing in using lazyAdapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, lazy-evaluation

I want to use lazyAdapter in this tutorial :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

but it is using xmlParser in this tutorial and i want to use JSON, so i am very confusing particularly i am beginner

can you help me please to replace xml with JSON ??

```
package com.fedorvlasov.lazylist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text.setText("item "+position);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ refer this url for json parsing.

you have to just replace the url http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml with yr url which gives json

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should parse the JSON data and replace XML with them. You can see this tutorial first: [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/). And i recommend to use [gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/Home), which user guide is here: [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)